# Change Notification Color through Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

In my current Version of my App, I want to implement a Notification System.

For that I already created two Preferences:

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="@string/notificationColor"
    android:summary="@string/notificationColorSummary"
    android:key="notificationColor"
    android:entries="@array/notificationColor"
    android:entryValues="@array/notificationColor"/>
```

The array contains the following:

```
<string-array name="notificationColor">
    <item>Default</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
</string-array>
```

And to send the Test Notification, this is the Preference:

```
    <Preference
    android:title="@string/notificationTest"
    android:key="notification_test"
    android:summary="@string/notificationTestSummary"/>
```

Now to the "real" Code. With this I create the Notification:

```
        Preference notificationTest = (Preference)findPreference("notification_test");
        notificationTest.setOnPreferenceClickListener(newPreference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_school_white_36dp);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("Timetable");
            mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, this is a test notification from your Timetable App!");
            //Set the normal Light
            mBuilder.setLights(0xff0000ff, 3000, 100);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // notificationID allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
            return true;
        }
});
```

And this is my OnPreferenceChanged:

```
    final ListPreference notificationColor = (ListPreference) findPreference("notificationColor");
    notificationColor.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

        if(notificationColor.getValue() == "Yellow") {
            //Overwrite the Color from the OnPreferenceClickListener (Blue) with Yellow

        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

What I want is already mentioned in my Code. Basically, I set a normal Color, and if the User changed the normal one, overwrite the OnPreferenceClicked with the Color selected.

Or is there a way to give the compete App a default Notification color, and change that afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

To change the colour of notification, you need to define custom view for notification. Then you can easily control the background and text colour.

Comment: The background and Textcolor isn't needed. I just need to change the notification light I once set with `mBuilder.setLights(0xff0000ff, 3000, 100)` (OnPreferenceClick) to the Color the user choosed (OnPreferenceChanged)